# How much data can be added to a Netty channel

Tags: java, client-server, netty

I am using Netty for a client server application. I want to add data to each channel like:

```
channel.attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("deviceId")).set(deviceId);
```

I have general questions:

1. How many attributes can I attach to channel
2. What is the max size of an attribute?
3. What types (Object, variables, arrays,...) can an attribute be?

Answer (score 3):

1. The `DefaultAttributeMap` stores attributes in an `AtomicReferenceArray`, so I would say you can store something around `Integer.MAX_VALUE` attributes, a few less actually. So more than 2 billion.
2. I have not tried this but I would say as much as your JVM heap size allows.
3. Attributes can be of any type:

   ```
   <T> Attribute<T> attr(AttributeKey<T> key);
   ```

   ---

   ```
   final static AttributeKey<Long> CHECKSUMKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("calcchecksum");
   final static AttributeKey<CustomClass> COMMANDKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("command");
   final static AttributeKey<Long> FILEHANDLEKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("filehandle");
   final static AttributeKey<File> PATHKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("destpath");
   ```

Comment: Although you can set as many as attributes as you wish, it's better defining a class with more than one property so Netty doesn't need to look up the table for each attribute but only once for a group of attributes.